# Why *strptr = 0 truncate the string?(C)

Tags: c

Why `*strptr = 0` truncate the string?(C)

Why the ascii value 30 of 0 become 0 of null?

Here I'm confused with the number 0, string 0 and the string termianl 0.

your explaination will be appreciated.

Comment: `0 == '\0'`, `0x30 == '0'`.

Comment: Smells like you wanted to write `*strptr = '0'`?

Comment: I am confuse here, 1 + 1 = 2, the ascii value of 1 is ?

Comment: @L.feir: The ASCII value of the `char` with value `'1'` is `0x31` (or `49` in decimal).

Comment: It's unfair to downvoe without reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More precisely, there are three lexical elements that contain a zero character: `0` (unquoted), `'0'` (quoted, typically (but not always) equal to `48` or `0x30` unquoted) and `'\0'` (equal to `0`, but in character notation).

The question is talking about two distinct values...`'0' != '\0'`. Forget about 30, 48, etc. Just remember `'0'` and `'\0'` are different characters, and `'\0'` is a string terminator that has a value of `0`...

I think you meant to use `'0'` (emphasis on the quotation marks).

Answer (score 3):

All standard library string routines treat character `'\0'` as string terminator, so if you put it at the beginning of the string - they all see no data to process, because first character is a terminator so effectively string is empty. And yes, per standard `'\0'` is a character that has value `0`. As result: `'\0' == 0` is true.